# How to get phone number of Skype contact?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, contacts, skype, phone-number

The contacts which added when using Skype are also listed in phone's People section and store the mobile number in "call mobile" field. Is there a way to retrieve this field's value? When I use Contacts API, those contacts show an empty "PhoneNumbers".

Comment: I think there's no way to do that, for now.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your and Christian's reply. I think there will be a way to do that.

Comment: Yes, probably with WP 8.1, which will include new APIs

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for do that in Windows Phone.